# visreg: overlay two models in a single plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I'm trying to draw in a single plot crude and adjusted GAM models using library `visreg`:

```
# Create DF
set.seed(123)
x1 = rnorm(2000)           
z = 1 + 3*x1 + 3*exp(x1)         
pr = 1/(1+exp(-z))         
y = rbinom(2000,1,pr)
df = data.frame(y=y,x1=x1, x2=exp(x1)*z)

# Fitting GAMs
library(mgcv)
crude <- gam(y ~ s(x1), family=binomial(link=logit), data=df)
adj   <- gam(y ~ s(x1) + s(x2), family=binomial(link=logit), data=df)

# Plot results using 'visreg'
library(visreg)
p.crude <- visreg(crude,  scale='response', "x1", line.par = list(col = 'red'), gg=TRUE) + theme_bw()
p.adj <- visreg(adj,  scale='response', "x1", gg=TRUE) + theme_bw()
```

Using `gridExtra` I can produce a two columns plot, however I would have a single plot which overlays the two model plots.

### [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `plot=FALSE` parameter to get the data without the plots:

```
p.crude <- visreg(crude,  scale='response', "x1", line.par = list(col = 'red'), plot=FALSE)
p.adj <- visreg(adj,  scale='response', "x1", plot = FALSE)
```

And, then re-create it by hand:

```
dplyr::bind_rows(
  dplyt::mutate(p.crude$fit, plt = "crude"),
  dplyr::mutate(p.adj$fit, plt = "adj")
) -> fits

ggplot() +
  geom_ribbon(
    data = fits, 
    aes(x1, ymin=visregLwr, ymax=visregUpr, group=plt), fill="gray90"
  ) +
  geom_line(data = fits, aes(x1, visregFit, group=plt, color=plt)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

https://github.com/pbreheny/visreg/blob/master/R/ggFactorPlot.R has all the other computations and geoms/aesthetics you can use in the recreation.